# Piping a command's output to ':' command

Tags: bash, pipe, sigpipe

I am updating an old script and came across a pattern I am unfamiliar with:

```
# NOTE The | : always returns true so the <cmd> doesn't fail
<cmd> | :
```

I've only ever seen this pattern used in a fork bomb example.  If someone were to ask me how to accomplish what is stated in the comment, I would have suggested:

```
<cmd> ||:
```

Before I chalk this up to a typo, has anyone seen this pattern and able to explain its use-case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a typo that also happens to have a similar effect. Differences:

- `cmd | :` pipes `cmd`'s stdout to `:`. Since `:` exits immediately, if `cmd` writes anything it will likely be hit with a SIGPIPE signal or EPIPE error, typically killing it.<sup>†</sup>
- `cmd | :` runs `cmd` in a subshell, nullifying environmental changes like `var=value` or `cd /dir`. Compare `cd /tmp || :` to `cd /tmp | :`.
- `cmd | :` won't work if `set -o pipefail` is enabled.

Based on the comment it should be `|| :`.

<sup><sup>†</sup> Technically, it's a race condition. `cmd` could write something before `:` exits, though it's unlikely. Or even more unlikely, if `cmd` wrote a lot it and filled up the pipe's buffer it would actually block *until* `:` exits, at which point its pending `write()` syscall would receive an EPIPE/SIGPIPE. You can simulate this with `strace -e write yes | { sleep 0.1; :; }`</sup>

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a way to suppress the standard output of the command, it would the equivalent to:

```
<cmd> > /dev/null
```

I see it usefull in scripts where you don't want to show the output of cmd

Comment: Not equivalent. `| :` will cause failure when the program on the left-hand side tries to write to its stdout after the copy of `:`/`true` has already exited, whereas `> /dev/null` will work for any arbitrary amount of content.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so, in a few words, if the output of cmd is too big it will produce an error?